# How to create dl tags and display data in it

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data and i want to display it in dl tags and i want to create new dl tags every time i loop through the json data, but the output i got is the dl will be created and closed before the dt and dd which were suppose to be inide it is created, you can see in the fiddle below [jsfiddle.net/buo28k1L/56/](http://jsfiddle.net/buo28k1L/56/). Below is my code i added style to the dl to show where the dl is formed and you can see that the dt and dd are outside of the dl instead of being inside it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
dl {
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

**JS**

```
  var data = [
  [{
    "id": "67",
    "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
    "id": "69",
    "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
      "id": "572",
      "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
      "id": "573",
      "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "579",
      "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
      "id": "580",
      "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "588",
      "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
      "id": "589",
      "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]
]

if (data.length > 0) {
  var content = $("#content");
  firstdata = data[0];
  secdata = data[1];

  for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
   // var d =  $( document.createElement('dl') );
    var dl = $("#content").append("<dl/>");
    dl.append("<dt href='" + firstdata[i].id + "'>" + firstdata[i].name + "</dd>");

    for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
      if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
        dl.append("<dd href='" + secdata[i][j].id + "'>" + secdata[i][j].name + "</dd>");
      }
    }
  }
  content.append(dl);
} else {
  console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake inside your first for loop. 
try this one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
   // var d =  $( document.createElement('dl') );
   //create an empty dl tag
    var dl = $("<dl></dl>");
    //append your dt
    dl.append("<dt href='" + firstdata[i].id + "'>" + firstdata[i].name + "</dt>");
    //append your all dd
    for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
        if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
           dl.append("<dd href='" + secdata[i][j].id + "'>" +secdata[i][j].name + "</dd>");
      }
    }
  //append each dl before starting new one.
  content.append(dl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `append()` incorrectly. What you can do is first create a HTML string with `dt` and `dd` so that this can be then added to `dl` and then append this `dl` to div with `id` as `content`. For further verification of below snippet, you can use browser `inspect element` and you will see that the HTML is rendered as

```
<dl>
  <dt href="67">Baby &amp; Toddler Clothing </dt>
  <dd href="572">Baby Clothing Accessories </dd>
  <dd href="573">Baby Shoes</dd>
</dl>
```

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "id": "67",
    "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
    "id": "69",
    "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
      "id": "572",
      "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
      "id": "573",
      "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "579",
      "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
      "id": "580",
      "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "588",
      "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
      "id": "589",
      "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]
]
if (data.length > 0) {
  var content = $("#content");
  firstdata = data[0];
  secdata = data[1];

  for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {
   // var d =  $( document.createElement('dl') );
    var dtHTML = "<dt href='" + firstdata[i].id + "'>" + firstdata[i].name + "</dt>";

    for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
      if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
        dtHTML += "<dd href='" + secdata[i][j].id + "'>" + secdata[i][j].name + "</dd>";
      }
    }
    $("#content").append('<dl>'+dtHTML+'</dl>');
  }
} else {
 console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```

```css
dl{
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with Javascript

```
if(data.length > 0) {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    firstdata = data[0];
    secdata = data[1];
    var dl = document.createElement('dl');
    for (var i = 0; i < firstdata.length; i++) {

        var dt = document.createElement('dt');
        dt.href = firstdata[i].id;
        dt.append(document.createTextNode(firstdata[i].name));
        dl.append(dt);

        for (var j = 0; j < secdata.length; j++) {
            if (secdata[i][j] !== undefined) {
                var dd = document.createElement('dd');
                dd.href = secdata[i][j].id;
                dd.append(document.createTextNode(secdata[i][j].name));
                dl.append(dd);
            }
        }
    }
    content.append(dl);
}
else
{
    console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem in a much simpler way by using the ``` template string (``) backticks ```.

Create your html structure using these ``` backticks(``) ```  and just append the content to the `div`

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "id": "67",
    "name": "Baby & Toddler Clothing "
  }, {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Kids' Clothing, Shoes & Accessories"
  }, {
    "id": "69",
    "name": "Costumes, Reenactment Theater"
  }],
  [
    [{
      "id": "572",
      "name": "Baby Clothing Accessories "
    }, {
      "id": "573",
      "name": "Baby Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "579",
      "name": "Boys Clothing [Sizes 4 & Up] "
    }, {
      "id": "580",
      "name": "Boys Shoes"
    }],
    [{
      "id": "588",
      "name": "Costumes"
    }, {
      "id": "589",
      "name": "Reenactment & Theater "
    }]
  ]
]
if (data.length > 0) {
  var content = $("#content");
  var dlList = data[0].map((dt, index) => {
    var ddList = data[1][index].map(dd => {
      return `<dd>${dd.name}</dd>`;
    }).join('');
    return `<dl>
      <dt>${dt.name}</dt>
      ${ddList}
    </dl>`;
  }).join('');
  content.append(dlList);
} else {
 console.log('no item for this categories');
}
```

```css
dl{
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```